# Cant understand why index for joining re.findall starts at 1 instead of 0

Tags: python, regex

Code from the book "Automate the boring stuff with python"

```
#! python3
# phoneAndEmail.py - Finds phone numbers and email addresses on the clipboard.

import pyperclip, re

phoneRegex = re.compile(r'''(
    (\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))?                # area code
    (\s|-|\.)?                        # separator
    (\d{3})                           # first 3 digits
    (\s|-|\.)                         # separator
    (\d{4})                           # last 4 digits
    (\s*(ext|x|ext.)\s*(\d{2,5}))?    # extension
    )''', re.VERBOSE)

# Create email regex.
emailRegex = re.compile(r'''(
    [a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+      # username
    @                      # @ symbol
    [a-zA-Z0-9.-]+         # domain name
    (\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})      # dot-something
    )''', re.VERBOSE)

 # Find matches in clipboard text.
text = str(pyperclip.paste())
matches = []

for groups in phoneRegex.findall(text):
       phoneNum = '-'.join([groups[1], groups[3], groups[5]])
       if groups[8] != '':
           phoneNum += ' x' + groups[8]
       matches.append(phoneNum)
for groups in emailRegex.findall(text):
       matches.append(groups[0])

# Copy results to the clipboard.
if len(matches) > 0:
    pyperclip.copy('\n'.join(matches))
    print('Copied to clipboard:')
    print('\n'.join(matches))
else:
    print('No phone numbers or email addresses found.')
```

It takes out emails and phone numbers in your clipboard. My problem is with the lines

```
for groups in phoneRegex.findall(text):
       phoneNum = '-'.join([groups[1], groups[3], groups[5]])
```

If i have understood it correctly the findall method returns a list of tuples where each tuple has each group of the regex something like

```
[(area code, separator, first 3 digits, separator, last 4 digits, extension), (area code, separator, first 3 digits, separator, last 4 digits, extension)]
```

But since lists and tuples start with indexes 0 and i want to join the first, third and fifth of each tuples items, why isnt that line

```
for groups in phoneRegex.findall(text):
       phoneNum = '-'.join([groups[0], groups[2], groups[4]])
```

Comment: the first group (0th index) for `re.` is *always* the full match. This is done this way so even when you don't have capturing groups `.group()` will still return the full match

Comment: Is this group hidden right at the beginning when creating the regex object or does it appear once i do a search or findall?

Comment: There's no "hidden". When you do `.search` or `.findall` or whatever regex function at all, you get multiple things - **the full match** and your own custom capture groups. The full match is the 0th index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python (and most other regex engines to be honest), The `re` `match` objects **always** have at least one group after a successful match. The first of them (0th index) is always the **full match**.

To illustrate what I mean by "full match". Here's this simple regex- `r'hello\s+world'`. This will match strings like `hello world` and `hello       world` and even `foo hello world bar`. Check out the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zIwlFP/1)

Now there will be 3 matches on that demo, and in all of them, you'll notice on the right it says "full match" and lists out the match, which for the first string is `hello world`, for the second is `hello       world` and for the third is `hello world`

*That* is the full match. It's just the full regex match without any capturing whatsoever.

Now here's another regex, that matches *and* captures- `r'hello\s+(world)'`. Check the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zIwlFP/2) for this one.

Now notice, each match has 2 fields, one is the **full match**, which is the same as last time and the other is **Group 1**. Which is our captured group - `world`.

In conclusion, after a successful match, the full match is always at 0th index, followed by the captured groups.

Read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group) for more info.